# Редирект в .htaccess без точных ссылок

Tags: html, .htaccess

форумчане. Есть сайт, с ним проблема. Прошу о помощи т.к не понял/не нашёл информации о редиректах в .htaccess.
Проблема состоит в чём. В .htaccess прописаны ссылки... Пример:

```
RewriteRule ^test.*$ /downloads/image.png [R=301,L]
```

При переходе по ссылке site.ru/test открывается либо скачивается изображение. 
Всё хорошо, но вот проблема в чём, при переходе по выше упомянутой ссылке, в адресной строке появляется точная ссылка к файлу site.ru/downloads/image.png
Как сделать так чтобы это изображение/страница открывались и при этом имели указанный адрес в htaccess без точной ссылки. (site.ru/test вместо site.ru/example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.*$ /downloads/image.png [L]
```

Comment: Пробовал, тогда документ html теряет (понятия не имею почему) css файл и страница отображается без стилей полностью.

Comment: проверьте пути к стилям, возможно они у вас отностительные и с /dir/dir открываются, а с /dir/ - нет.

Comment: Ваша правда, указал в html файле точные ссылки стилей и ссылка стала отображаться так как мне было нужно. Спасибо большое!